# Complex number differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

What is the first order derivative of $(e^y+1)^{ik}$ with respect to y? Here k is any integer and i is a complex number.

Cheers
Ronnie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(e^y+1)^{ik}=e^{ik(\log(e^y+1)+i2n\pi)}$$ and the derivative is

$$ik\frac{e^y}{e^y+1}e^{ik(\log(e^y+1)+i2n\pi)}=ik\frac{e^y}{e^y+1}(e^y+1)^{ik}.$$

Comment: differentiable in a chosen branch, right?

Comment: @felasfa: I have added a term $i2n\pi$, which actually makes no difference..